# Amazon API MWS SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now. None of the solutions on other questions are working.

What I'm trying to do is get my list of orders on Amazon. To do this, I am making a call to Amazon MWS. However, this is the error message I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>03686743-15a6-4207-b0b7-316d1e4e5c8f</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

To find out what was wrong, I went onto Amazon MWS Scratchpad and used the same values, even the timestamp (I think you have 15 minutes until it expires), and compared the signatures. They were the same. However, my program still got the same error while the scratchpad worked perfectly.

Here is all the code:

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib
from time import gmtime, strftime
from requests import request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_timestamp():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime())

def calc_signature():
    """Calculate signature to send with request"""
    sig_data = method + '\n' + domain.replace('https://', '').lower() + '\n' + URI + '\n' + request_description
    hmac_obj = hmac.new(str(SECRET_KEY), sig_data, hashlib.sha256)
    return  urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(hmac_obj.digest()), safe='-_.~')

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
SELLER_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
MARKETPLACE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Action = 'ListOrders'
SignatureMethod = 'HmacSHA256'
SignatureVersion = '2'
Timestamp = get_timestamp()
Version = '2013-09-01'
CreatedAfter = '2014-08-26T23:00:57Z' # TODO -1 day
URI = '/Orders/2013-09-01'
domain = 'https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk'
method = 'POST'

payload = {'AWSAccessKeyId': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
           'Action': Action,
           'SellerId': SELLER_ID,
           'SignatureVersion': SignatureVersion,
           'Timestamp': Timestamp,
           'Version': Version,
           'SignatureMethod': SignatureMethod,
           'CreatedAfter': '2014-08-26T23:00:00Z',
           'MarketplaceId.Id.1': MARKETPLACE_ID
          }

request_description = '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, urllib.quote(payload[k], safe='-_.~').encode('utf-8')) for k in sorted(payload)])

sig = calc_signature()

url = '%s%s?%s&Signature=%s' % (domain, URI, request_description, urllib.quote(sig))
headers = {'Host': 'amazonwebservices.co.uk', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'x-amazon-user-agent': 'python-requests/1.2.0 (Language=Python)'}

response = request(method, url, headers=headers)
print response.content
```

Here's a print of `sig_data` in `calc_signature()`:

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.co.uk
/Orders/2013-09-01
AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&Action=ListOrders&CreatedAfter=2014-08-26T23%3A00%3A00Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&SellerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-08-28T15%3A50%3A34Z&Version=2013-09-01
```

Here's a print of `url`:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Orders/2013-09-01?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxx&Action=ListOrders&CreatedAfter=2014-08-26T23%3A00%3A00Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=xxxxxxxxxxxx&SellerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-08-28T15%3A50%3A34Z&Version=2013-09-01&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am completely out of ideas at this point. I have triple checked that my secret key, access key, seller ID and marketplace ID are correct.

Any help would be massively, massively appreciated!

Comment: You were `urllib.quote`-ing the signature twice. Inside yor `calc_signature` and outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a few months late but I had the exact same issue despite knowing my signature was correct and found out it was in fact the POST execution that was the problem and not the signature.  If Amazon can't understand your params, it will throw an HTTP 403 error and tell you your signature is wrong even though it's not.  I can't tell you why it works this way but try skipping the requests library and doing the following using urllib.request after building your url instead which worked for me:

```
#using python 3.4

import urllib.request

#... your code from before...

headers = {'Host': 'mws.amazonservices.com', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'x-amazon-user-agent': 'SomeApp/1.1 (Language=Python)'}
req = urllib.request.Request(method=method,url=url,headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print(the_page)

#As seen here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#data
```

If that doesn't do it, take a second look at how you encoded everything and maybe dabble with urllib.parse.

Happy Amazoning!

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `calc_signature` function, your `safe` parameter isn't allowing `+` and `/` which are allowed in the base64 output character set. As a result, it is percent-encoding them, and then those percents get further perecnt-encoded as `%25`s in the query string.

I made some additional changes, so here's all the code:

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib
from time import gmtime, strftime
from requests import request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_timestamp():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime())

def calc_signature(method, domain, URI, request_description, key):
    """Calculate signature to send with request"""
    sig_data = method + '\n' + \
        domain.lower() + '\n' + \
        URI + '\n' + \
        request_description

    hmac_obj = hmac.new(key, sig_data, hashlib.sha256)
    digest = hmac_obj.digest()

    return  urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(digest), safe='-_+=/.~')

SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SELLER_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
MARKETPLACE_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

Action = 'ListOrders'
SignatureMethod = 'HmacSHA256'
SignatureVersion = '2'
Timestamp = get_timestamp()
Version = '2013-09-01'
CreatedAfter = '2013-08-26T23:00:57Z' 
URI = '/Orders/2013-09-01'
domain = 'mws.amazonservices.com'
proto = 'https://'
method = 'POST'

payload = {
    'AWSAccessKeyId': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Action': Action,
    'SellerId': SELLER_ID,
    'SignatureVersion': SignatureVersion,
    'Timestamp': Timestamp,
    'Version': Version,
    'SignatureMethod': SignatureMethod,
    'CreatedAfter': CreatedAfter,
    'MarketplaceId.Id.1': MARKETPLACE_ID
}

request_description = '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, urllib.quote(payload[k], safe='-_.~').encode('utf-8')) for k in sorted(payload)])

sig = calc_signature(method, domain, URI, request_description, SECRET_KEY)

url = '%s%s?%s&Signature=%s' % \
    (proto+domain, URI, request_description, urllib.quote(sig))

headers = {
    'Host': domain,
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    'x-amazon-user-agent': 'python-requests/1.2.0 (Language=Python)'
}

response = request(method, url, headers=headers)

print response.content
```